# reshape long to wide and keep duplicate ids

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a data frame looks like this:

df:
[image]

df:

I'd like to reshape to desired output as following, reshape long to wide by ID and if checked value is yes or no, in my dataframe both yes and no has the same length by ID, sequence of value under Yes or No is not required (only keeps different values by duplicated IDs by Yes or No column):

[image]
I tried pivot or reshape but didn't really save all values of the same id. What would be the best way to achieve above desired output?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] and read [ask]

Comment: what logic makes you put 11 and 33 in the same row instead of putting 11 and 44 in the same row? what happens if there are more Yes than No? Do you fill the missing values with NaN?

Comment: Sequence of values under Yes or No subgroups is not required, the output could be 11 and 44 in the same row, as long as they are under desired colomn of Yes or No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to take the mask `df['Checked'] == 'Yes'` and copy these lines. And then add a 'Checked - No' column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'Checked': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
    'Value': [11, 22, 33, 44, 1, 2, 3, 4]
})


df1 = df.loc[df['Checked'] == 'Yes', ['ID','Value']]
df1.rename(columns={'Value': 'Checked - Yes'}, inplace=True)
df1['Checked - No'] = df.loc[df['Checked'] == 'No', 'Value'].values

print(df1)
```

Output

```
   ID  Checked - Yes  Checked - No
0   1             11            33
1   1             22            44
4   2              1             3
5   2              2             4
```

Comment: Thank you i ended up trying this approach as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Primarily I do not think the format you want the original DF to be reshaped in is very fortunate. You will run into problems with that format if there are missing values and the readability of that format is not optimal. Anyway the closest solution I can think of is using `pivot_table` with appropriate `aggfunc`:

```py
df.pivot_table(index="id", values="value", columns="checked", aggfunc=tuple)
```

which yields

```
checked        no       yes
id
1        (33, 44)  (11, 22)
2          (3, 4)    (1, 2)
```

In this case a tuple will be created for every item in the DF. Of course increasing the length of the items will have a negative effect on printing. In that case you can take use of `numpy.array` truncating functionality. Unfortunately you cannot use `aggfunc=numpy.array` directly. Instead you can pass it a wrapper class:

```py
class Values:
     def __init__(self, items):
         self.items = np.array(items)

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.items)

df.pivot_table(index="id", values="value", columns="checked", aggfunc=Values)
```

Don't forget to set some reasonable `numpy.printoptions`

```py
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=3, edgeitems=1)
```

This will produce something like this:

```py
checked       no          yes
id
1        [66 77]  [11 ... 55]
2          [3 4]        [1 2]
3            NaN          [5]
```